# Why Do Some Related Entities Persist and Not Others in RIA Services?

Tags: silverlight, wcf-ria-services

I'm having a lot of troubles with RIA Services. I'm really wondering if it's worth the hassle at all. The problem I have now is similar to other problems: related entities. Let's say I have a class, Foo. Foo has two related entities, Bar and Fighter.

If I'm working on a new Foo, foo, and I want to add something to the Bars collection, it works just fine. Like:

```
foo.Bars.Add(new Bar{A=a, B=b});
```

But when I try to add a Fighter, it doesn't work:

```
foo.Fighters.Add(new Fighter{C=c,D=d});
```

I've been all around the interwebz looking for the solution. I've found the suggestions to use the [Include] attribute and the [Associated] attribute as well. Both have worked in some cases. But they're not working in this case and I have zero clue why. I've deleted and re-created my EDMX and my DomainService because someone suggested it, but it isn't working.

So what is wrong and what other information do you need to help me out? When I say try to add a Fighter to my foo.Fighters collection, it's not persisting the add. I will note that I'm trying to add an *existing* Fighter in my specific example, not a *new* Fighter, if that helps/gives clues.

If you need information or real code samples, I'll be happy to oblige. Thanks in advance to all that try to help.

Comment: When you say 'Not persisting' - do you mean it's not being added to the EntitySet at all? Or it's not persisting across Application reloads? If the latter, are you calling context.SaveChanges() ?

Comment: I've verified that it is being added to the EntitySet, but on the service side, I check and the Fighter is not added. When I reload, it's not in the data set. But everything has been saved to the database EXCEPT that the Fighter is not added to the FooFighter table (it just maps Foos to Fighters). So the Fighter is not in the collection upon a reload. I call SubmitChanges, not SaveChanges.

Comment: There has to be something wrong with my relationship. I even added a method with the Invoke attribute above it in the DomainService that takes in a Foo and a Fighter. I then say foo.Fighters.Add(fighter) and then call SaveChanges on my context. It STILL isn't saving!

Comment: I re-created the EDMX and now the new method with the Invoke attribute actually works. But I still think I'm doing something wrong because I shouldn't have to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A number of things to check and confirm

1. The Fighter table has a foreign key defined in the database.
2. Use `[Association]`, `[Include]`, and `[Composition]` attributes. Association defines the relationship. Include instructs the server to send the instance or contents of the collection to the client, if populated. Composition instructs WCF RIA to track changes to the collection and send them back to the server.
3. Ensure you are calling `context.SubmitChanges()` after all the adds in Silverlight.
4. Ensure you have an insert method on your DomainService.

Maybe one or more of these will help.

Comment: Up vote for the good suggestions, I'll check all of these... I have an Association attribute already. The Include attribute had no effect. I've tried the Composition attribute, but it isn't right for this situation: Fighters aren't a part of Foos, they can just be associated with them. So putting the Composition attribute on Fighters really locks it down. I'm calling SubmitChanges. I have an Insert method for the Foo table. When I call SubmitChanges, the Fighter is there. When I get to the InsertFoo method, the Fighter is NOT there. Thanks for the ideas, though.